# Determine the continuity of the function given the following parameters

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

continuity problem:

[image: continuity problem]

I'm confused by the following. I evaluated the equation when x = 2, and calculated the answer to be 16-11 = 5

So I figured there was a jump at x = 2, where f(2) is defined, but there is a hole in the polynomial when x approaches 2. However, the statement is True.

Where am I going wrong in my thinking?

Comment: You're essentially evaluating the limit of the function at x=5. Since the function is given to be continuous at x=5, the limit will be the same as the actual value of the function, f(5)=4. So it's true. The question doesn't ask anything about f(2).

Comment: Ah, so I was just reading it wrong. Pretty much:
 f(5) is equivalent to f(4x^2 - 11), and both f(5) and f(4x^2-11) evaluate to 4?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g: x\mapsto 4x^2-11$.

As $f$ is continuous at $x_0=5$,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 5} f(x)=f(5)=4 $$

Moreover, $g$ is continuous at $x_1=2$ so

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}g(x)=g(x_1)=5=x_0$$

Hence $f \circ g$ is continuous at $x_1 =2$.

Therefore,

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow2} f(4x^2-11) = \lim_{x \rightarrow2} (f\circ g)(x) = \lim_{y \rightarrow5} f(y)=f(5)=4$$